# Help with Linear Algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, vectors

[image: consider two vectors]

Hi. I am unsure as how to proceed with this question (part b). I understand that $v_1$ and $v_2$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, so I know they must be linearly independent. Besides that I don't have much of an idea.

Comment: Are there any examples of such a question in your notes or in your text book?

Comment: It would greatly improve your Question if you make it more self-contained.  Mathematical expressions can be posted using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $~~(x_1,x_2)=y_1(1,1)+y_2(2,-1)=(y_1+2y_2,~~ y_1-y_2)$ Now try to express $y_1$ and $y_2$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and convert them to matrix form.

Answer (score 0):

Write row vectors $v_1, v_2$ as a matrix and perform elementary row operations. If you can get a zero vector in either row, then the vectors are linearly dependent.

for part b)
Provided $x=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, find $y=(y_1,y_2)$ such that
$x= v_1y_1 + v_2y_2$
$x = (1,1)y_1 + (2,-1)y_2$

As for the matrix part: it's really saying
$$\left (\begin{array}{c}y_1\\y_2\end{array}\right ) = \left (\begin{array}{cc}m_{11}&m_{12}\\m_{21}&m_{22}\end{array}\right ) \left (\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right ) $$